# Alternative for joining two tables multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2008-r2, database-performance

I have a situation where I have to join a table multiple times. Most of them need to be left joins, since some of the values are not available. How to overcome the query poor performance when joining multiple times?

## The Scenario

#### Tables

[Project]: ProjectId Guid, Name VARCHAR(MAX).
[UDF]: EntityId Guid, EntityType Char(1), UDFCode Guid, UDFName varchar(20)
[UDFDetail]: UDFCode Guid, Description VARCHAR(MAX)

Relationship:
[Project].ProjectId - [UDF].EntityId
[UDFDetail].UDFCode - [UDF].UDFCode

The UDF table holds custom fields for projects, based on the UDFName column. The value for these fields, however, is stored on the UDFDetail, in the column Description.
I have lots of custom columns for Project, and they are stored in the UDF table.

So for example, to get two fields for the project I do the following select:

```
SELECT 
    p.Name ProjectName,
    ud1.Description Field1, 
    ud1.UDFCode Field1Id,
    ud2.Description Field2,
    ud2.UDFCode Field2Id
FROM
    Project p
    LEFT JOIN UDF u1 ON
        u1.EntityId = p.ProjectId AND u1.ItemName='Field1'
    LEFT JOIN UDFDetail ud1 ON
        ud1.UDFCode = u1.UDFCode
    LEFT JOIN UDF u2 ON
        u2.EntityId = p.ProjectId AND u2.ItemName='Field2'
    LEFT JOIN UDFDetail ud2 ON
        ud2.UDFCode = u2.UDFCode
```

## The Problem

Imagine the above select but joining with like 15 fields.  In my query I have around 10 fields already and the performance is not very good. It is taking about 20 seconds to run. I have good indexes for these tables, so looking at the execution plan, it is doing only index seeks without any lookups. Regarding the joins, it needs to be left join, because Field 1 might not exist for that specific project.

## The Question

Is there a more performatic way to retrieve the data?
How would you do the query to retrieve 10 different fields for one project in a schema like this?

Comment: Is it too late to save your UDFs as XML? This is a MUCH better way to go.

Comment: Yes, it is. Because the db schema is from a third party. So I'm not able to modify the main structure. I can add my own tables in the schema, but I need to keep the default structure unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

Your choices are `pivot`, explicit aggregation (with conditional functions), or the `join`s. If you have the appropriate indexes set up, the `join`s may be the fastest method.

The correct index would be `UDF(EntityId, ItemName, UdfCode)`.

You can test if the group by is faster by running a query such as:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM p LEFT JOIN
     UDF u1
     ON u1.EntityId = p.ProjectId LEFT JOIN
     UDFDetail ud1 
     ON ud1.UDFCode = u1.UDFCode;
```

If this runs fast enough, then you can consider the `group by` approach.

Comment: It took 20 seconds. More than doing the left joins individually. Almost the same, actually.

Comment: It is possible that doing a `pivot` is faster. I suspect that it is better optimized to take advantage of indexes.  But, that may not make a difference when you have two joins.

Comment: My indexes are good. The operation is index seek for each data retrieval operation.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this very weird contraption (it does not look pretty, but it does a single set of outer joins). The intermediate result is a very "wide" and "long" dataset, which we can then "compact" with aggregation (for example, for each ProjectName, each Field1 column will have N result, N-1 NULLs and 1 non-null result, which is then selecting with a simple MAX aggregation) [N is the number of fields].

```
select ProjectName, max(Field1) as Field1, max(Field1Id) as Field1Id, max(Field2) as Field2, max(Field2Id) as Field2Id
from (
    select
        p.Name as ProjectName,
        case when u.UDFName='Field1' then ud.Description else NULL end as Field1,
        case when u.UDFName='Field1' then ud.UDFCode else NULL end as Field1Id,
        case when u.UDFName='Field2' then ud.Description else NULL end as Field2,
        case when u.UDFName='Field2' then ud.UDFCode else NULL end as Field2Id
    from Project p
        left join UDF u on p.ProjectId=u.EntityId
        left join UDFDetail ud on u.UDFCode=ud.UDFCode
) tmp
group by ProjectName
```

The query can actually be rewritten without the inner query, but that should not make a big difference :), and looking at Gordon Linoff's suggestion and your answer, it might actually take just about 20 seconds as well, but it is still worth giving a try.